# Any ideas on how to turn certain cells absolute?

Tags: excel

Here is my spread sheet:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is break down my total weight into individual weights, to do this I have to make total weight absolute so I can multiply my % ratios. Only problem is some skus have 6 items some have 5 items so I can't just set every X rows make absolute. essentially I want to do this.

[image]

P.S. I have about 5000 rows so it'd take a really long time to manually do it. Wondering if there's any solutions thanks.

Comment: You can ctrl+V an image to embed it into your post as opposed to using an external hosting service.

Comment: New users with no rep can't embed images directly into their posts.  I think that takes either 10 or 50 rep score to do that.  It prevents site abuse by Trolls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested if functions, it's dirty but it works:

1. The function goes in J column
2. Check if the associate H column is empty
3. If it is empty return empty to keep the spreadsheet clean
4. If it is not empty check the row above in I column for empty
5. If it is not empty that the total weight to multiply the ratio by the total weight
6. If it is empty check the row above that
7. And repeat as necessary.

I wrote this function that checks 5 deep I think? You could keep nesting it to check 10 deep, 20 deep, etc., until you reach the nested IF limit in excel which I think is 255 so that it adapts to your varying needs in the items list.

=IF(H7<>"",IF(I6<>"",H7*I6,IF(I5<>"",H7*I5,IF(I4<>"",H7*I4,IF(I3<>"",H7*I3,IF(I2<>"",H7*I2))))), "")

Comment: That's amazing thanks, the problem is the way i get total weight is by Index + match the names of the skus from a different sheet and some of them are blanks how does that affect this formula ??

Comment: If theyre blank theyll keep testing to the nest you put in place or return blank.

Comment: basically if you have blank total weights itll break the formula. you cant solve your problem without using vba. If you are open to vba I can write a script for it, It'd be much more elegant.

Comment: Although what I read I dont think youd ever get a blank as you are adding the index. So in this case, while its dirty, it should work. But without seeing the whole I cant say.

Comment: 0 != Blank in this case

Comment: If you could help me out with a VBA script, it would be appreciated. I'm just noticing the flaw right now when total weight is blank. Also there will be blanks for index + match because I have the sheet set up as only calculate the total weight when we sell that item. Some weeks we don't sell that item.

Comment: I've edited the sheet and reuploaded the imgur.

http://imgur.com/a/hSwCz

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying - you don't want any calculation if the total weight is blank? I.e: you're not selling it that week? Disregard my previous comments if that is the case because I was missing your point.

Comment: Awesome let's see what you can spin up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just want the J column filled based on the H column, but here's my suggestion. I tend to use hidden columns as they keep my formulae simple but you can incorporate the formula in my G column (the column I'ld hide) into my formula in the F column.

[Results Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLsDX.png)

[Formulae Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKE9y.png)

P.S. I need reputation as I need to comment on another post.

Sryn

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden column with nested If statements, formula goes in Column K:

1. Check if Column F is blank
2. If it is not check if the row above is blank
3. Repeat
4. Once the row is blank you know you are on the row with the total weight
5. Set the Column K cell to that value (the I column)

For column J:

1. If Column K is 0 then return empty
2. If not multiply Column H by Column K

The formula for Column K is:

=IF(F22 <> "", IF(F21 <> "", IF(F20 <> "", "", I20), I21)) - just add the required amount of nesting, for your case 6 nests is enough

The formula for Column J is:

=IF(K22 = 0, "", K22 * H22)

And then just right click column K and choose to hide that column. Of if you use column K in another part of your sheet just select any unused column.